# Auto start and shutdown for Azure Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, virtual-machine

Looking for a solution to schedule daily shutdown for vms at night 8PM and auto start the vms by morning 8 AM. Is there any way to get it done from Azure itself?

We tried the VM capability option under VMs overview page, But there is no option to auto restart. ANy help highly apprecicated..

Comment: The auto shutdown feature is on the VM itself, but as you noted there is no auto start. I've frequently resort to an Azure Automation Account Runbook to solve this

Comment: Any guidance to achieve  this?

Comment: Here's a solution guide I've used previously for [Automation Account impl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management)

And here is a newer, and much simpler time-to-live impl with [Logic Apps](https://github.com/anirudhgarg/functions-logicapp-startstopvms#:~:text=The%20Start%20VM%20and%20Stop%20VM%20functionality%20is,App%20and%20click%20Edit%20and%20Click%20Code%20View.)

Also Sven's answer is acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use Azure Logic Apps. All you need is a scheduler and the action. There is also already a template for your requirement. Additionally, Azure helps you set up the logic app.

Check out this, it's really simple.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-examples-and-scenarios

[image]

**A few notes:**

- Use consumption plan for the app.
- A runbook would also work, but it takes longer to set up and you need
  some PowerShell.
- Do not confuse Stop with Deallocate. You need Deallocate
  if you want to save money.
- What you have to pay attention to with a logic app as well as an
  automation account: You need a user / a service principal who has the
  right to start and stop the VM. For this you should use Manged
  Identity (exists for both resources). You then grant this identity
  the right to start and stop the VMs via IAM.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. This is a good answer.